# Dynamically add class when sections hit top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a website and would like to add some jQuery functionality to a page. Basically, the page has a sidebar with a menu (showing all sections of this one page). I have added the functionality that when you click a menu item, the main section scrolls down to the proper section.

I've managed to add an active class on these menu items when they are clicked using jQuery. See:

```
$('#category-list li a').click(function(){
    $('#category-list li a').removeClass("category-list-active");
    $(this).addClass("category-list-active");
});
```

But I'd like to add the same functionality for when the user scrolls down the page (AKA when one section hits the top of the page, the corresponding menu item get's the active state class).

Since the site is in development for a client, I can't really show it but if I need to I can re-create something similar.

Thanks in advance,

- Andy

Comment: You will need to add a handler for window scroll (and potentially resize) and calculate which elements are on screen based on their position and the scroll position of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
var fl = $("#your-section").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if(this.scrollTop() > fl) {
    // do your stuff
   }
 })
```

You may have to play with the offset to find the exact position where the transition should take place.